# Google Sheets Search Multiple Columns

Tags: regex, google-sheets, search, filter, textjoin

How can I get the search function to look through multiple columns?

```
=(FILTER(P1:Y500,search(F5(T1:T500)+(U1:U500))))

=(FILTER(P1:Y500,search(F5(T1:T500+U1:U500))))

=(FILTER(P1:Y500,search(F5(T1:U,U1:U))))

=(FILTER(P1:Y500,search(F5,T1:U+U1:U)))
```

These obviously don't work, but I can't figure it out. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=FILTER(P1:Y500; REGEXMATCH(T1:T500&U1:U500; F5&""))
```

Comment: You are the smartest person. I love you. Thanks!